# Saving UV mesh Selection

Tags: uv

Is there a way saving a selected UV selection so when I click on the selected area it gets the mesh active again? Most times I accidentally click off the area of the UV selection, and then I have to reselect all mesh of the UV area I want to map again.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey :). When you deselect an area accidentally, just Undo a step (*ctrl + z*) and the selection will be back. Blender is awesome :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done via vertex group. As you choose your selection open "object data properties" create new vertex group and click "assign" now whenever you click on that group and choose select, your verteces will be selected again.
[image]

Comment: Just to add - you can also use *Face Maps* (work the same but for faces) :).

Comment: Thanks for that Fowl, exactly what I was looking for.

Cheers.